# how to make an input field readonly at first an then make it editable on the click of a button in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, readonly, input-field

//these are my 2 divs which i have to make readonly at first or bydefault then on a click of a edit button i want to remove the readonly and make it editable

```
 <div>
     <input type="text" 
     placeholder="Example@scio.com" v-model="userDetails.email ">
   </div>

  <div>
   <input type="text"  placeholder="+91 860 420 3001"  
    v-model="userDetails.contactNumber">
</div>
```

//this is my icon on the click of which the above action should get performed!!

```
<img class="pencil-image" 
src="/static/images/pencil-edit-button@2x.png" 
@click="editProfile">
```

please help me with a solution which will work in vuejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="app">
<input type="text" :readonly="shouldDisable" v-model="text"> <button @click="clicked">Edit</button>
<hr>
<p>The value of input is: {{text}}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: 'text',
    shouldDisable: true
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
        this.shouldDisable = false
    }
  }
})
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/2dcngmzb/)

Comment: thanks its working i would also like to know that if i am apllying the same logic on datepicker component of vue then it is not working do u have any solution for making the datepicker vue's component readonly and then editable on the click of a button ??

Comment: hmm your question is clear but i need to show some code,or it would be better to make a new question about it

Comment: i tried it with disablepicker feature of vue component and i was able to do it thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `<input>`'s `readonly` attribute to a data property. For example, if your component had a `readonly` property, you could bind to it like this:

```
<input :readonly="readonly">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      readonly: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editProfile() {
      this.readonly = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" :readonly="readonly" placeholder="Example@scio.com">
  <button @click="editProfile">Make input editable</button>
</div>
```